# Static binary instrumentation or binary rewriting tools and frameworks for C++

Tags: c++, dll, instrumentation

I am working on ways to implement static binary instrumentation on unmanaged C++ dlls or executables to obtain profiling data.
I want to insert print statements which will print the methods's name itself to the console. 
I do not want to use dynamic binary instrumentation(DBI) tools such as valgrind,DynamoRio due to large overhead.
I came across various Bytecode static instrumentation tools and frameworks for C#,JAVA (such as C#-Cecil,MBEL,RAIL. JAVA-Javassist,BCEL,reJ,Serp,JMangler).
 But did not find enough resources for C++.
Are there tools or frameworks which will allow us to inject code to an unmanaged C++ dll or exe, or do a static binary instrumenation?
I came across tools like Dyninst,EEL,ERESI,PEBIL(for linux) but there are not enough resources which will show the correct implementation of static binary instrumentation.

Answer (score 2):

**LLVM** can do static binary instrumentation. [HERE](https://llvm.org/docs/) is the documentation of LLVM.

We also can learn SBI implemented by LLVM in [github](https://github.com/banach-space/llvm-tutor). And it provides a specific instrumentation project [here](https://github.com/banach-space/llvm-tutor#injectfunccall).

What's more, for instrumentation of C++, there is another [project](https://github.com/sampsyo/llvm-pass-skeleton/tree/rtlib).